# adding another data in ajax submit

Tags: php, ajax, upload

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function image_gen_file(){
    var data = new FormData();
    $('.file').each(function(i) {
        $.each(this.files, function(j) {
            data.append('image_' + i, this);
        });
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: baseurl + "/image_maker/file",
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data){
            $(".image_genx").html(data);
        }
    });

}

</script>
```

the above code push files to 'image_maker/file' now i want to also push an post 'id' .. id=23
i tried to do like below but its not working..

In 'image_maker/file' it will validate if the files are images.. and to insert in database it needed an 'id'

```
    $.ajax({
        url: baseurl + "/image_maker/file",
        data: data + "id=23",
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data){
            $(".image_genx").html(data);
        }
    });

}

</script>
```

Comment: @RajeshDante it depends how you are fetching the data in "file" page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't it be

```
data.append("id","23");
```

data is a FormData object , not a string.

Comment: Great, please consider answering the question, the green tick.

Answer (score 0):

try putting ampersand before id to separate that id is another variable.

```
 data: data + "&id=23",
```

Edit:

P.S. How your `data` looks like?

Comment: @xdazz, sorry my mistake, i just read his second code carefully